# Assume $T$ is compact operator and $S(I- T) = I $.Is this true that $(I- T)S =I$?

Tags: functional-analysis

Suppose $S,T \in {\rm B}(X)$ and assume $T$ is compact operator and $S(I- T) = I $.Is this true that $(I- T)S =I$?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! I would suggest you to explain a little bit your thoughts about it, so other people could help you better. Good luck!

Answer (score 5):

Yes, your hypothesis implies that $(I-T)$ is injective, which, by the Fredholm alternative means that it is surjective as well. By the bounded inverse theorem, this means $(I-T)$ is invertible in $B(X)$, and so its right and left-inverses must coincide.

Comment: Why does the assumption imply that $(I-T)$ is injective?

Comment: Because $\ker(I-T) \subset \ker(S(I-T))$