# The necessity of compactness of $T$ for the invertibility of $I-T$

Tags: functional-analysis

[In this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1325810/assume-t-is-compact-operator-and-si-t-i-is-this-true-that-i-ts-i), quoted below, $T$ is a compact operator. Why is this   condition necessary?

> Suppose $S,T \in {\rm B}(X)$ and assume $T$ is compact operator and $S(I- T) = I $. Is this true that $(I- T)S =I$?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Since the original question you link to is very short, it would be helpful if you repeat that question here.

Comment: The word "necessary" is unfortunate here.  The compactness of $T$ is sufficient for invertibility; if you remove that condition and don't replace it with anything else, then invertibility will no longer follow; but that condition is not *necessary* for invertibility, in that just because $I-T$ is invertible doesn't mean $T$ is compact.  (For example, $I-\lambda I$ is invertible for most scalars $\lambda$.)

Answer (score 1):

Without compactness, $I-T$ could be, for example, the forward shift operator on $\ell^2$, with $S$ being the backward shift.